# OLE DB Release Configuration Problem

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, oledb, release

When I compile my C# WPF project in release configuration mode with Visual Studio 2008 and run the project on my computer I have no problem at all. If I move the Release directory onto another computer (that does not have Visual Studio) everything seems to work except OLE DB. This is probably because the other computer does not have what is necessary for OLE DB. How can I include OLE DB in the release configuration so that it will work on other computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the OS of the target system, you may need to install the appropriate [Microsoft Data Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=78CAC895-EFC2-4F8E-A9E0-3A1AFBD5922E&displaylang=en).  The appropriate runtime will depend on the OLE DB driver you are using (the latest, linked above, doesn't include JET drivers, for example, since they're no longer "maintained" by MS), and the operating system you are trying to target.

Note that XP Service Pack 2 includes the above linked runtime.  If you're targeting Jet (MS Access), you'll need to install an older MDAC runtime.